# Upload files with Dropzone multipart only upload last part (chunk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload big files(videos) in multipart with Dropzone js to Wasabi(AWS copy). The error I got is that only uploads the last chunk. and I don't know why but the dropzone last call don't compile the file. I tried different ways and no one worked to me. This is my dropzone object:

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone('#video-dropzone', {
            previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview-template').innerHTML,
            parallelUploads: 2,
            thumbnailHeight: 120,
            thumbnailWidth: 120,
            method: 'POST',
            paramName: "file",
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            timeout: 7200000,
            maxFilesize: 500000,
            chunking: true,
            parallelChunkUploads: false,
            chunkSize: 100000000, {# 1000000000   1GB per part #}
            params: function (files, xhr, chunk) {
            if (chunk) {
                return {
                    UploadId: chunk.file.upload.uuid,
                    PartNumber: chunk.index,
                    TotalFileSize: chunk.file.size,
                    CurrentChunkSize: chunk.dataBlock.data.size,
                    TotalChunkCount: chunk.file.upload.totalChunkCount,
                    ChunkByteOffset: chunk.index * this.options.chunkSize,
                    ChunkSize: this.options.chunkSize,
                    Filename: chunk.file.name,
                };
            }
        },
            init: function () {
                thisDropzone = this;
                {# When a file is added, we need to put the fields of the video, #}
                {# so we show a video create form #}
                thisDropzone.on('addedfile', function (file) {
                    thisDropzone.options.url = $("#video-dropzone").attr("action");
                    $.confirm({
                        title: "{% trans 'Video Create' %}",
                        content: 'url:{% url 'video-create' %}',
                        useBootstrap: false,
                        theme: 'material',
                        buttons: {
                            create: function () {
                                {# If the title is empty, you can't create it #}
                                if ($("#id_title").val() == "") {
                                    $("#id_title").addClass("is-invalid");
                                    return false;
                                }
                                {# Creation of the video fields #}
                                let create_video = video_create(file);

                                {# If all fields has been created correctly,#}
                                {# the generate a signature and launch the queue #}
                                if (create_video.status == 200) {
                                    file.customName = create_video.data.filename;

                                    generar_signature(file);

                                    {# When all fields are correct, the dropzone can start#}
                                    {# to upload the files #}
                                    thisDropzone.processQueue();
                                }

                            },
                            cancel: function () {
                                {# Removes the file if you click cancel #}
                                thisDropzone.removeFile(file);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                });
```

It chunks the file correctly, but when finish in the storage I only see the last part

Comment: Will you post your server-side code as well, so we can see how you're handling the upload on the server side?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting, that starting with release 6.0.0-beta2, Dropzone supports AWS S3 multi-part uploads out of the box.

See https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/main/test/test-sites/2-integrations/aws-s3-multipart.html for integration guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time chunk is called it calls the API .
Hence it stores the last chunk only.
You have to store each chunk into a byteArray (global) and process it accordingly