# How to upload images in chunks to AWS S3 using Dropzone

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload images in chunks directly to an AWS S3 bucket from the frontend web app using [Dropzone](https://www.dropzone.dev/), but I can't find any workable guide or examples out there.

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70753357/6764929) it should be possible to do this out of the box with Dropzone v6+, although I can't find any documentation about it on Dropzone website or GitHub repo. There seems to be only this example on Dropzone's GitHUb repo: https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/main/test/test-sites/2-integrations/aws-s3-multipart.html. I tried to make it work with Dropzone v5 and v6, but it always fails on line 68 with the error "dataBlocks is undefined".

Can anyone provide any guidance on how to upload image chunks from Dropzone to a S3 bucket using S3 multi part API (either S3 Rest or S3 JS SDK)? Is this even possible to be done directly (Im thinking about auth issues here) or do I have to proxy the Dropzone chunks to S3 via my server?